# signer is not valid

Tags: iphone

"Brian's iphone" because the signer is not valid."

Please tell me how to resolve it as it is coming when i'm testing the .ipa file in my iPhone device

Answer (score 2):

Did you tell the people who created such an ipa your device's UDID? If not, that person need to know your UDID and re-sign the binary with a new provisioning profile containing your UDID.